# Check if key-value combinations can be found in Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am looking for a function `found_in_color_dict()` which tells me if a certain key-value combination can be found in `color_dict`. The function returns True or False, respectively.

```
color_dict = {"a":"blue", "b":"green", "c":"yellow", "d":"red", "e":"black", "f":"white"}

checkpoints_1 = {"a":"blue"}
checkpoints_2 = {"a":"green"}
checkpoints_3 = {"a":"blue", "d":"red"}
checkpoints_4 = {"a":"blue", "d":"red", "f":"white"}
checkpoints_5 = {"a":"blue", "d":"red", "f":"purple"}
```

Based on the example I would expect the following results:

```
found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_1)
>>> True

found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_2)
>>> False

found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_3)
>>> True

found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_4)
>>> True

found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_5)
>>> False
```

I can only think of complex approaches to solve this problem. But I guess there might be an easy way to solve it, right?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Comment: Sure. Please give me a moment, I will add it to my post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset):

Note: *`dict.itemview` acts as a set*

```
def found_in_color_dict(checkpoint):
    return checkpoint.items() <= color_dict.items()
```

---

```
>>> found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_1)
True
>>> found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_2)
False
>>> found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_3)
True
>>> found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_4)
True
>>> found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_5)
False
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `set` (`checkpoint.items() <= color_dict.items()`), `items()` already behaves like a set ;)

Comment: @mozway Didn't even think of that. Edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you. Very simple (=great) solutions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all()` like so:

```
color_dict = {"a":"blue", "b":"green", "c":"yellow", "d":"red", "e":"black", "f":"white"}
def found_in_color_dict(d):
    global color_dict
    return all(i in color_dict.items() for i in d.items())
```

Test code:

```
checkpoints_1 = {"a":"blue"}
checkpoints_2 = {"a":"green"}
checkpoints_3 = {"a":"blue", "d":"red"}
checkpoints_4 = {"a":"blue", "d":"red", "f":"white"}
checkpoints_5 = {"a":"blue", "d":"red", "f":"purple"}

print(found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_1),
found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_2),
found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_3),
found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_4),
found_in_color_dict(checkpoints_5))
```

Output:

```
True False True True False
```